# Add quotation mark inside new/old.colname in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I am building some trigggers using mysql. One of them is checking if the inserted value is exist or not in database.

When the trigger comparing the date value. It will return in 0 rows. I tried it with appending quotation around new.column name but it literally read as 'new.column'. Not '2017-11-15' as example.

Here's the code :

```
BEGIN
declare jumlah int;
declare stok_awal int;
declare stok_akhir int;
set @jumlah:=(select count(*) from stok where stok.id_barang=new.id_barang and stok.tgl_stok=date(new.tgl));
 //I need help for above line code
if (@jumlah IS NULL)
then
insert into stok (stok.id_barang,stok.tgl_stok,stok.jml_terbeli,stok.stok_akhir) values (new.id_barang,new.tgl,new.jumlah,new.jumlah);
else

set @stok_awal:=(select stok_awal from stok where tgl_stok=date(new.tgl) and id_barang=new.id_barang);
//I also need help for above line code

set @stok_akhir:=@stok_awal+new.jumlah;
insert into `stok`(id_barang,tgl_stok,jml_terbeli) values (new.id_barang,new.tgl,new.jumlah);
end if;
END
```

Any help please?
Thankyou

Comment: Why declare jumlah then use @jumlah? I would prefix declared variables with a v just in case...

Comment: stok.tgl_stok=date(new.tgl) - is this right should it be =date(new.tgl_stok)?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice that until @P.Salmon commented.
It was trully my mistake in giving variable name. It was conflict by colname.
I changed the code to something like this

```
set v_jumlah:=(select count(*) from stok where stok.id_barang=new.id_barang and stok.tgl_stok=date(new.tgl));
```